# Given that $m \dot v \cdot v = 0$ , how is it equal to $m \frac{d}{dt} (v \cdot v)/2$?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, differentiation, calculus

While studying about scalar triple product in vector algebra, I stumbled upon the following question with the solution.

[image: scalar triple product application]

I want know how is  $m \dot v \cdot v $ = $m \frac{d}{dt} (v \cdot v)/2$?

Comment: Start with the right hand side and use the product rule.

Comment: You can remove everything and keep only the last sentence you wrote. $d/dt(f(t)^2)= 2 f(t) d/dt (f(t))$ by using the famous chain rule, or also the product rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple case of the product rule.

$$\frac{m}{2} \frac{d}{dt} (v \cdot v) = \frac{m}{2}\left[ \left(\frac{d}{dt}v\right) \cdot v + v \cdot \left(\frac{d}{dt} v\right)\right]=\frac{m}{2}\left( \dot{v} \cdot v + v \cdot \dot{v}\right) = \frac{m}{2} \,2\,\dot{v}\cdot v = m \dot{v} \cdot v$$

Comment: given the title, maybe it is worth mentioning that the fact $v \dot v =0$ is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just what I needed !!!

Comment: Note that this implicitly assumes that the vector dot product is commutative, which it is given that the vectors $v$ and $\dot v$ are elements of the real three dimensional Cartesian space. This assumption of commutativity is not necessarily valid in other spaces.